# mysql service crash (ubuntu server)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, innodb

mysql service craches and the server becomes down everyday or every two days and I do not know the reason (I am using apache and innodb).

**mysql error log:**

> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size   = 2G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer   pool
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140139774727936 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is   authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is   Barracuda.
> 2022-03-12 11:11:22 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from   checkpoint LSN=2195305514
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are   active.
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data   file: "ibtmp1"
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for   temporary tables
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12   MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.24 started; log sequence number 2195305523
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140139204437760 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142364764096 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
> Version: '10.2.20-MariaDB-1:10.2.20+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142235891456 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142235891456 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> 2022-03-12 11:11:23 140142235891456 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> 2022-03-12 11:11:24 140139204437760 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220312 11:11:24

Comment: There is nothing about a crash in that log, just a regular startup. Please provide more context.

Comment: are you sure you have enough space left in your /var directory ?

Comment: yes, i am sure @ZarehKasparian

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.